# Python livestream to RTMP server (Flash Media Server clone?)

Tags: python, video-streaming, rtmp, fmle

I would like to play around with coding an application that could capture a desktop or section of a screen (height and width variables for resolution) and stream those to an RTMP server (rtmp://server.com/live).

I saw something called **rtmplite**, but the description of this package is:

> "This is a python implementation of the Flash RTMP server"

So I would ultimately like to achieve the following, but will implement it in pieces as I go along, without getting overwhelmed at the project scope:

1. Make connection to RTMP server (with authentication where needed) to channel on ustream.com, justin.tv/twitch.tv, own3d.tv, etc.
2. Ability to select height, width selection of desktop or entire desktop and stream live to that channel, as if I was using Flash Media Live Encoder.

Really I just want to make my own Python-based FMLE or Xsplit application so I can stream live on my own without using those applications.

Any libraries you can send me to read up on that explain this FMLE-clone type process or information would be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did some RTMP streaming from python for the wiidiaplayer project: http://wiidiaplayer.org. This is by no means a full solution, but at least some RTMP functionality has been implemented in python there.

Unfortunately it has been a long time since I touched that code; if you have any questions feel free to ask them; I'm not sure how much of the answers I will be able to provide.